# How to generate a heatmap

Tags: r

I'm practicing heatmap coding, I'm self-learner, I feel stuck, with the annotations, labeling, and colors. I want to get the same heatmap as in this photo (sorry for the bad quality), so I need helps with:

-the dots at the bottom of the plot

the data are in this [link](https://github.com/learnseq/learning/raw/main/GSE133399_Fig2_FPKM.csv):

[image]

It seems the heatmap is based on the z-score of the mean of the 4 groups, since they have two groups, I figured may be the team generated a mean of each two columns and derived z-score from the mean for these four groups.
I tried this code, but I feel stuck:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)
library(matrixStats)
library(pheatmap)
library(heatmaps)

dfc <- read.csv(url("https://github.com/learnseq/learning/raw/main/GSE133399_Fig2_FPKM.csv"))

head(dfc)

dfg <- dfc %>% dplyr::filter(tracking_id %in% c(
    "Ifng", "Igfbp7", "Il13", "Il4", "Itgb1", "Rbpj",
    "Tnfsf11", "Xcl1", "Ern1", "Furin", "Il5", "Nrp1", "Ptprs",
    "Spry1", "Vdr", "Foxp3", "Prdm1", "Itgb8", "Lamc1", "Ptpn5",
    "Bmpr2", "Csf1", "Dst", "Myo1e", "Pmaip1", "Itgav", "Ramp1",
    "Sdc4", "Areg", "Calca", "Capg", "Ccr2", "Cd44", "Il10", "Il1rl1",
    "Maf", "Rora", "S100a4", "Adam8", "Adam19", "Anxa2", "Bcl2l1",
    "Csda", "Ehd1", "Hist1h1b", "Id2", "Il2ra", "Il2rb", "Lgals1",
    "Lmna", "Mki67", "Penk", "Podnl1", "S100a6", "Vim")) 

dfg$CD44low_rep <- rowMeans(dfg[,c('CD44low_rep1', 'CD44low_rep2')], na.rm=TRUE)
dfg$CD44hi_CD69low_rep <- rowMeans(dfg[,c('CD44hi_CD69low_rep1', 'CD44hi_CD69low_rep2')], na.rm=TRUE)
dfg$CD44hi_CD69hi_CD103low_rep <- rowMeans(dfg[,c('CD44hi_CD69hi_CD103low_rep1', 'CD44hi_CD69hi_CD103low_rep2')], na.rm=TRUE)
dfg$CD44hi_CD69hi_CD103hi_rep <- rowMeans(dfg[,c('CD44hi_CD69hi_CD103hi_rep1', 'CD44hi_CD69hi_CD103hi_rep2')], na.rm=TRUE)
head(dfg)
dim(dfg)
head(dfg)
rownameshm <-paste(dfg[,1])
rownameshm
colnameshm <- paste(dQuote(colnames(dfg[0, 10:13])), collapse = ", ")
colnameshm
dfg$Mean <- rowMeans(dfg[,10:13])
dfg$sd <- rowSds(as.matrix(dfg[,10:13]))
head(dfg)

zScore <- function(p){
for(n in 10:13){
    p[[n]]=(as.numeric(p[[n]])-as.numeric(p[[14]]))/as.numeric(p[[15]])
    }
return(p)
}

Matrix_zScore <- t(apply(dfg,1,zScore))
head(Matrix_zScore)
Matrix_zScore_temp <- mapply(Matrix_zScore[,10:13], FUN=as.numeric)
Matrix_zScore_temp <- matrix(data=Matrix_zScore_temp, ncol=4, nrow=55)
Matrix_zScore_temp1<-as.data.frame(Matrix_zScore_temp)
head(Matrix_zScore_temp)
```

My heatmap looks like this:
[image]

Comment: @DanY thank you for the tip, I updated the question, if you run my code, you get different heatmap from the figure, I'm looking for help to replicate the map in the question, sorry I did not express this in my question.

Comment: It seems like you're pretty close. Have you played with the arguments to `pheatmap`? See the `?pheatmap` help page for details. Elaborating on DanY's point, it would be helpful to know what aspects you see as gaps that need fixing. Do you need help removing the dendrograms? Do you need help making it tall and skinny instead of squareish? Do you want the color scheme to be a closer match? Adding row labels? The **e** at the top? The dots at the bottom?

Comment: @GregorThomas it seems you hit the points, lol...you are right, I tried this `pheatmap(Matrix_zScore_temp, dendrogram='none', Rowv=TRUE, Colv=TRUE,trace='none')` but it did remove the dendrograms, but I do need help with all what you mentioned in addition to the labeling on the sides.

Comment: @GregorThomas I updated the question, it seems that I'm asking too much, I'm looking for bit concise code to get the same original heatmap. I'm still beginner, I hope that my question doesn't bother contributors here.

Comment: Complex question. Have you thought about doing this in ggplot instead?

Comment: @oscartorom I'm open to any suggestion, but I have no extensive experience with ggplot. If you have any suggestion I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Try to separate the analysis.
Get your inputs, then get your final output, then use that final output with a ggplot heatmap.
From experience I can tell you the color scale used is RdBl.
Then with ggplot you start modifying the graph layer by layer, and attack your problem that way.
E.g.
1. First get a heatmap.
2. Google how to change labels.
3. Adding additional plots.
I am just suggesting ggplot as I understand it more and it sort of has an order.
Other than that, your question is more like 6~7 different questions in one.
Good luck! I learnt R by myself as well btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to get close using ggplot:

```r
library(ggplot2)

rownames(Matrix_zScore_temp) <- dfg$tracking_id
plot_frame <- reshape2::melt(Matrix_zScore_temp)

ggplot(plot_frame, aes(Var2, Var1, fill = value)) + 
  geom_tile(color = "white") +
  scale_y_discrete(position = "right") +
  labs(y = "", fill = "") +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = c("#3C57A8", "white", "#DE2D29")) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @AllanCameron ! that was really helpful, How can I the dots underneath the plot? my code seems so primitive compared to yours. I appreciate your support.